# WebStorm JS Libraries TypeScript Community Stubs not showing list

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, libraries, stubs

I might be missing something obvious but I can't figure out what.

I recently installed WebStorm on my new computer and had no problem downloading TypeScript Community Stubs libraries like Angular, Mongoose etc. from the settings (I downloaded about 6 and could see the entire list while doing so).

Now, today I'm doing exactly the same thing but only get the three (see screenshot). Is anyone in the same situation? I don't think it's necessary related but I did update to 2017.1 so maybe it's something in the version...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a recent refactoring in DefinitelyTyped.

This is the issue tracking it : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15367#issuecomment-289161919

Comment: In WebStorm it's tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26160 and marked as fixed already -- will be included in 2017.1.1. Possible workarounds for now can be found in comments.

Comment: Ok great thanks, I figured it happened at around the same time I updated to 2017.1 but I was just worried I'd changed some settings. I only started using community stubs a week ago